# JavaScript crypto libraries?

Tags: javascript, cryptography

What are some of the secure/reliable crypto libraries for JavaScript? For those who have used it, what are your opinion about them? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Google Closure**

Used Google's closure library quite successfully for a while

https://developers.google.com/closure/library/

Specific `crypt` documentation here

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_crypt.html

**phpjs.org**

Occasionally for simpler tasks I have also used self-contained functions such as [md5](http://phpjs.org/functions/md5/) or [sha1](http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1/) from [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/)

**crypto-js**

Although never used personally, I heard very good things about this library

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: You can see a list of crypto library in this gist : https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441/